# Access SQL Server data in SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, sql-server

I have an existing Asp.Net solution which stores data into SQL Server 2008 database.

I would like to reference that SQL server data in SharePoint Online list. What would be the best way to do it?

One solution I was thinking of implementing was

- Create a SQL Azure database and make my Asp.Net application write data into the Azure database.
- Reference that Azure database information as External content type data in SharePoint Online.

I want to find out what are the alternative solutions and their advantages.

Answer (score 1):

This recommended way you can access SQL server data in Sharepoint online out-of-the-box Using BCS.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/178875.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj943762.aspx

The other solution would be using 3rd party tools and connectors.

http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/cloud-connector/Pages/SQL-Sync-to-Office365.aspx

Comment: thank you, I am mainly looking for connecting to local sql server database and not Azure database. We dont have license for Azure cloud services

Comment: So the third party solution would work for you. Or you have to write your own custom solution using CSOM to syn data between these two.

Comment: thank you Aanchal, Layer2 seems like a good product, I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is a remote event handler: Create a provider hosted app where the remote event handler is hosted on an on-prem server and the app portion is deployed to SP Online. So, if someone adds/changes a list item, the remote event handler will be called, and it could modify the list item with data from an internal database.

Though, I said "possible" because, while MS definitely states that this scenario is possible, there is no documentation that I can find that shows how to configure it, or how authentication/security would work for the remote event handler.

Comment: Thank you Mike, that is interesting. I think I will probably use this idea sometime in future. I am mainly looking for getting the information from local sql server(not azure ) to SharePoint Online.

Comment: According to MS, a provider hosted app can be hosted on your hardware. So, it could be used to work with an on-premise SQL database. But again, I said "possible", because while this seems like it would be a simple solution, MS provides no details on how to actually configure this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Business Connectivity Services for your SharePoint online.

Please refer the following URL.

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj943762.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Can you connect BCS to On premise SQL server.

Comment: Yes you can also configure BCS for your on premise SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg454740(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg454740%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Writing a Rest service can do the job.
Thank you all for your guidance.

Comment: Hi Nate, You mentioned a Rest service can do the job can you please elaborate maybe it can help me?
Thanks in Advance